# Why should I prefer HTML5 to HTML4 in this case?

Tags: html

**HTML 5**

```
<section>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
</section>
```

**HTML 4**

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Both of these have to be aligned by CSS. What exactly is the use of HTML 5?  Yes there are form tags in HTML 5 that are very useful, but I'm concerned with the above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One word: semantics.

See http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/building_web_pages_with_html_5/#Semantic_structure_at_last

EDIT: To paraphrase the article, by request (and rightly so), HTML 5 has added a set of new tags, such as `article`, `section`, `nav`, `header`, `footer`, and others that have, traditionally, been created manually in HTML 4 by using `div` tags and semantic ID values (eg. `<div id='header'>`.

By creating these new semantic tags, it allows for easier to understand markup for humans, as well as being easier to parse semantically by machines.  For example, it will be easier to write code that crawls web pages looking for article content (think blog search) with a standardized tag, rather than having to search pages full of `div`s.

Comment: I was reading about HTML 5, and therefore had to ask this.   For more complicated scripting, I have to rely on Javascript, jquery.  From HTML 3 to HTML 4 there is a vast difference, its totally table less.  To make it less clutter, why use HTML 5

Comment: Please paraphrase the text in the link that you provided. This answer has been accepted as the best one, if the link breaks - so does the context of the accepted answer. In the future, making a link the driving force in a question or answer is usually a bad idea, for that reason.

Answer (score 5):

A few reasons off the top of my head:

1) It's more explicit and space saving to separate specific components of your website **Example:**

```
<section>
    <article>
    </article>
</section>
```

vs.

```
<div class='section'>
    <div class='article'>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's also takes up less space to directly reference each of these parts in CSS or JavaScript.

2) Similarly, it can be easier for screen readers and the like to extract useful information from a page for those who are blind or visually impaired.

Comment: There are screen readers already that can read off the web page.

Comment: There's always room for improvement.